# Is it normal to crave for lemons after running

Tags: running, nutrition

About 1-2 hours after running yesterday evening, I was cooking some salsa in my kitchen.

When adding some lemon juice to the salsa I suddenly had a craving for the lemon and basically  ate half a lemon.

Is this craving caused by the running? If so, does it indicate that my body was missing some kind of nutrition, that it was hoping to get from the lemon?

Comment: I think its off-topic for this site, but lemons are delicious! When I remember to buy them, I can eat 1-2 a day.

Comment: What were you drinking during and after your run? Were you specifically trying to include electrolytes?

Comment: I drank some bottled water before, and lots of water after the running. No special care for electrolytes. It was a 30min run by the way.

Comment: You might be a little bit overanalyzing... Just because you ate half a lemon (hey, if you were saying "I can't stop until I eat ten lemons each time after I exercise" then it might be a different history). Besides that, nearly everybody loves lemons! I eat between 1 and 3 daily.

Comment: @Mephisto While I like a little lemon juice on many meals, I had NEVER the urge to just bite into a lemon, so it was certainly a special/weird desire for me.

Comment: @JensSchauder there is a first time for everything. An "urge" for eating *half a lemon* that is in front of you when you are cooking seems to me nothing special... Maybe it was your first time, but my life is full of such impulses everytime I am in the kitchen... The difficult thing is to resist them when the targets are not fruits, but cheese, meat, cream... It is human nature. If you were trembling and your hands shaking and you ate twelve lemons and had constipation because magnesium excess or something similar, well, that might be another question...

Comment: Does anybody mind explaining to me what exactly is unclear about this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to a [random internet chart](http://www.betterraw.com/2011/10/what-do-food-cravings-say-about-you.html) that I'm not entirely sure I trust, craving acidic things is a sign of a magnesium deficiency.

If you're low on magnesium, it's likely you're low on other electrolytes. It's one of those things you'll sweat out and need to replace. You might want to consider drinking some sort of electrolyte mixture instead of water, or taking electrolyte tablets.

My personal (anecdotal) experience is that after an hour or more of sweaty exercise, I'll tend to crave water, salt and sour, and that drinking electrolyte-laced water during exercise helps significantly.